# Is it unneccesary to break setInterval if element is removed?

Tags: javascript

I use setInterval as below and until now i have used it exactly same way but if element is removed from Document this interval will continue to work unnecessarily. I haven't seen an example that handle this case yet.

Is it unnecessary to handle this case ? And if i have to handle it so what would be best way break interval ?

```
var element = $('bla');
setInterval(function () {
    element.text(new Date().toString());
}, 1000);
```

Comment: If it's just one interval that runs something that simple every second, you'll never notice it being there, and it probably won't throw any errors as jQuery is good at silencing those, but it would be good practice to clear the interval anyway me thinks,

Comment: @adeneo—nothing to do with jQuery. The object (DOM element) assigned to *element* exists as long as there's a reference to it, regardless of whether it's removed from the DOM or not. Using jQuery just means there's a much bigger object left lying around.

Answer (score 3):

Just a comment:

@hicurin, you might consider using an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) instead:

```
(function() {
  var element = $('bla');
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    element.text(new Date());

    // check if element is removed
    if(!$('bla').length && interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}());
```

Comment: Task: Find a way to detect element removal without re-executing the selector! I'd give you an upvote :-)

Comment: Simplest and probably fastest is likely `if (!document.getElementById(...))`, or perhaps `if (!element.parentNode)`, but only if the element itself is removed. There are others, but they are likely less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var element = $('bla');
var int = setInterval(function () {
    element.text(new Date().toString());
    // check if element is removed
    if(!(element.length > 0) || element == undefined){
      clearInterval(int);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: But how do you detect that element is removed ?

Comment: @Freshblood: By using that code inside the setInterval. See RobG's answer. The IIFE is unnecessary but look at where the `if` statement is located.

Comment: `element` won't become cleared just because the element was removed from the DOM…

Comment: I mean that `element.length` will never change on its own, the variable will not simply become `undefined`

Comment: Ok guys! I just try to give my suggestion so,... Sorry I didn't finish my answer. Now I have finished it.